# How to multiply two columns in a dataframe when one column has nans

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, operators

I have a dataframe like this

```
data= {'A':[np.nan,1,3,np.nan],'B':[np.nan,2,np.nan,8]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['A','B'])
print(df)
```

I want to do a multiplication operation like

```
df['C']=df['A']*df['B']
```

But as the column have nan values it gives me this error

```
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

So let me know how to make this multiplication possible.
eg: np.nan*8 = np.nan --->should give me like this

Thank you so much !!

Comment: use `df['C']=df['A'].mul(df['B'])`

Comment: ``df.assign(C=df.prod(1, skipna=False)``

Comment: btw what is your pandas version? bcz in `'1.2.4'` this `df['C']=df['A']*df['B']` works fine!!

Comment: Same answer as @AnuragDabas for '`1.3.0'`.